# How to achieve a certain number of page loads per second without caring how many child requests there are under a parent sample?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I want to achieve a throughput of 1 web page load per second.

As a simple test, I recorded all requests (HTTP request samplers) which occur when a page is loaded, grouped them under a Transaction Controller with the Generate Parent sample checkmark.

So I have a simulation of what hapens when a page is loaded and in this sense my page load is the Parent sample generated by the Transaction Controller.

Now, I want to use a timer to achieve 1 page load per second.
I chose a Constant Throughput Timer and set the target throughput to 60 samples per minute.

If I have only one HTTP Request sampler under the Transaction Controller, I can achieve 1 Transaction per second.
But if I have 2 or more which is normally the case, the throughput gets split among the 2 ore more samplers.

[image]

Is there any way in which I don't have to calculate the necessary target throughput based on how many HTTP Request samplers there are under the Transaction Controller?

I would just like to only worry about the throughput of the Parent sample and not the child requests, if there is a solution...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how do you configure the Constant Throughput Timer it will apply either to a single thread or all threads.

So you need to set it up like this:

[image]

I also believe it will apply to all the Samplers in its [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) so you need to divide the throughput by the number of the Transaction Controller's children.

You may find [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin) or [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer) easier to use as in that case JMeter will maintain the desired throughput no matter how many samplers or threads you have.